# incrementing date with a variable in php

Tags: php, date

I am trying to increment a date variable with say N number of days but i am getting the wrong value if i pass the number of days through variable  but working if i use integer as shown below:

working  scenario :--------------------------

```
$date="05-09-2015";

$a=date('d-m-Y', strtotime($date. ' + 90 days'));

echo $a;
```

the above code will increment the  date with 90 days .

failing scenario:----------------------

```
$date="05-09-2015";

$incd=90;

$a=date('d-m-Y', strtotime($date. ' + $incd days'));

echo $a;
```

The above code will return invalid result like 01-01-1970 .. ?? :(

any clue how to make it working .

Comment: Change the single quotes to double quotes and learn about how PHP handles strings and interpolation

Comment: `$a=date('d-m-Y', strtotime($date. " + $incd days"));` single quote does not work with variables like you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$date="05-09-2015";

$incd=90;

$a=date('d-m-Y', strtotime($date. ' + '. $incd .' days'));

echo $a;
```

Please let me know, if there is any issue.